# How to sort by presence of value or null with Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to sort a table by two columns. For the first column, I want to sort by the presence of a value or NULL.

Unworking code to illustrate what I want to do :

```py
MyModel.objects.order_by('blop IS NULL', 'name')
```

I've tried to use annotate but didn't find a way to define an expression to setting a field, or an aggregation function to return a boolean from a field.

Unworking code to illustrate what I tried:

```py
MyModel.objects.annotate(has_blop=F('blop IS NULL')).order_by('has_blop', 'name')
```

I think i could manage using conditional annotation (Case... When...) but it seems overkill.

The database used is postgres.

Comment: `MyModel.objects.order_by(ExpressionWrapper(Q(has_blop=None), BooleanField()).asc(), 'name')`.

Comment: Sorry, `MyModel.objects.order_by(ExpressionWrapper(Q(blop=None), BooleanField()).asc(), 'name')`.

Comment: Thanks it works ! Didn't expect it to have to use ExpressionWrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by the condition `Q(blop=None)`. It however requires an [**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) to convert the condition to a boolean field:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

MyModel.objects.order_by(
    ExpressionWrapper(Q(blop=None), BooleanField()).asc(),
    'name'
)
```